# UJS fails in application.js callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I have a simple comment system when I can dynamically add replies and I am trying to add a UJS way of allowing the user to cancel the reply.  I have a text field with id="comment_reply_content" and followed with an

```
<input id="cancel_reply" data-remote="true" class="btn btn-mini" type="button" value="Cancel">
```

In my application.js file I added:

```
$('#cancel_reply').live('ajax:success', function() {
   alert('hello');   
   // $('#comment_reply_content').val('');
});
```

No matter what I do I can't get this to work.  I commented out the actual functional javascript that clears the form etc. but now I have resorted to a simple alert for testing.  Placing the alert alone in my application.js works fine.  I have *.js files in my controllers which are working to create the new reply forms etc. so I know that UJS is working.  I am pretty sure I am just missing something easy here.  I have tried changing the `live` to `bind` with no success.